# Counting number of vowels in input of given words

Tags: c, string, loops

Count the number of vowels in a word
Please write a program to count how many vowels (‘a’, ‘e’, ‘i’, ‘o’, ‘u’) in a list of input words. Your program reads the words one by one and prints the number of vowels occurring in each word. Each word consists of only alphabets in mixed cases. The program repeats this process until hitting the word “exit” (case-insensitive). In this case, terminate the program after printing the number of vowels in “exit”. After termination, the program shall ignore remaining inputs, if any.

Input: Multiple words spanning across lines.
Each word shall consists of no more than 50 characters.
The words are separated by white spaces.

Output: The number of vowels in each of the input word, separated by newline.
That is, one number on a line.

```
Sample run #1:

I
1
went
1
apple
2
school
2
by
0
BUS
1
Exit
2

Sample run #2:

I go to school
1
1
1
2
by QQ email
0
0
3
Ai yAh Oooops
2
1
4
um
1
eXiT ignore these please
2
```

I am writing a code for this program and tried this code. It seems to give the correct output but still doesnt give full credit on my school code checker. What seems to be the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int isVowel(char c);
int isExit(char* c);

int main(void)
{
    char s1[51];
    int N, i, v = 0;
    int noExit = 1;

    while (noExit)
    {
        fgets(s1, 51, stdin);
        N = strlen(s1);

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (isExit(&s1[i]))
            {
                printf("2\n");
                noExit = 0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (isVowel(s1[i]))
                {
                    v++;
                }
                else if (s1[i] == ' ' || s1[i] == '\n')
                {
                    printf("%d\n", v);
                    v = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int isVowel(char c)
{
    c = toupper(c);
    if (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U' || c == 'a'
            || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int isExit(char* c)
{
    if ((toupper(c[0]) == 'E') && (toupper(c[1]) == 'X')
            && (toupper(c[2]) == 'I') && (toupper(c[3]) == 'T'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Each *word* can be up to 50 characters. Lines may be longer and the posted code doesn't handle longer lines correctly.

Comment: You wrote `c = toupper(c);` but you still checking lowercase vowels....

Comment: Moreover `isExit` can address the array out of bounds, for example if `c = &s1[49]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems that could explain a lower score:

- You limit yourself to lines of 50 characters.  The school test runs might have longer lines which you might mishandle.  The specification says the words are limited to 50 characters, but the lines might be longer. You should use `scanf()` to read one word at a time.
- you exit the program whenever to see the sequence `exit`, even in the middle of a word, this is too strong and not required: the requirements as you stated is *The program repeats this process until hitting the word `exit` (case-insensitive). In this case, terminate the program after printing the number of vowels in `exit`.*
- You use `toupper(c)` where `c` has type `char`.  This has potential undefined behavior if `c` is negative.
- You uppercase the character in `isVowel()`, but still compare it to the lower case vowels.
- `c` is a poor choice of name for a `char *`, better use `s` or `str`.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int isVowel(char c);
int isExit(const char *c);

int main(void) {
    char s1[51];
    int i, v;

    while (scanf("%50s", s1) == 1) {
        for (i = v = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (isVowel(s1[i])) {
                v++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", v);
        if (isExit(s1))
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int isVowel(char c) {
    c = toupper((unsigned char)c);
    return (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U');
}

int isExit(const char *s) {
    return (toupper((unsigned char)s[0]) == 'E'
         && toupper((unsigned char)s[1]) == 'X'
         && toupper((unsigned char)s[2]) == 'I'
         && toupper((unsigned char)s[3]) == 'T'
         && s[4] == '\0');
}
```

Comment: Point 3 is the expected behavior: _The program repeats this process until hitting the word “exit” (case-insensitive)._ And also point 2 can be expected behavior.

Comment: @LPs: the requirements are actually precise: `exit` is supposed to be a word and must be handled like the other words. Answer updated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes exiting the program with the sequence 'exit' is required and printing the numbe of vowels for it os required as well

Answer (score 1):

Just a demo for vowels count.

```
$ ./a.out this is a demo string
[this]
{'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'i': 1, 'o': 0, 'u': 0, 'cnt': 1}
[is]
{'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'i': 1, 'o': 0, 'u': 0, 'cnt': 1}
[a]
{'a': 1, 'e': 0, 'i': 0, 'o': 0, 'u': 0, 'cnt': 1}
[demo]
{'a': 0, 'e': 1, 'i': 0, 'o': 1, 'u': 0, 'cnt': 2}
[string]
{'a': 0, 'e': 0, 'i': 1, 'o': 0, 'u': 0, 'cnt': 1}
```

---

```
// Count Vowels

// Enter a string and the program counts the number of vowels in the text.
// For added complexity have it report a sum of each vowel fount

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct vowel_count
{
    int a;
    int e;
    int i;
    int o;
    int u;
} vowel_count_t;

bool
is_vowel(char ch)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

vowel_count_t
count_vowel(char *str)
{
    int i, c;
    vowel_count_t vct;

    vct.a = 0;
    vct.e = 0;
    vct.i = 0;
    vct.o = 0;
    vct.u = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        c = tolower(str[i]);  // lower && upper
        if (c == 'a')
            vct.a++;
        else if (c == 'e')
            vct.e++;
        else if (c == 'i')
            vct.i++;
        else if (c == 'o')
            vct.o++;
        else if (c == 'u')
            vct.u++;
    }

    return vct;
}

void
print_vowel_cnt(char *str)
{
    int i, c = 0;
    vowel_count_t vct;

    // method 1
    vct = count_vowel(str);

    printf(
        "{'a': %d, 'e': %d, 'i': %d, 'o': %d, 'u': %d, 'cnt': %d}\n",
        vct.a, vct.e, vct.i, vct.o, vct.u,
        vct.a + vct.e + vct.i + vct.o + vct.u
    );

    // method 2
    // for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    // {
    //     if (is_vowel(tolower(str[i])))
    //         c++;
    // }
    // printf("{'total': %d}\n", c);

}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <str1> <str2> ...\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("[%s]\n", argv[i]);
        print_vowel_cnt(argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```